# JSON to line string

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json, linestring

I'm getting a JSON return like so:

```
[{"lat":38.660274,"lng":-90.136198},{"lat":38.6613,"lng":-90.13860199999999},{"lat":38.664634,"lng":-90.141853},{"lat":38.664634,"lng":-90.141853},{"lat":38.664305999999996,"lng":-90.142608},{"lat":38.664305999999996,"lng":-90.142608},{"lat":38.65996,"lng":-90.137664},{"lat":38.656954999999996,"lng":-90.135108},{"lat":38.653724,"lng":-90.133544},{"lat":38.650299,"lng":-90.132881},{"lat":38.650299,"lng":-90.132881},{"lat":38.644039,"lng":-90.132278},{"lat":38.642413,"lng":-90.132567},{"lat":38.634983,"lng":-90.139129},{"lat":38.634983,"lng":-90.139129},{"lat":38.633693,"lng":-90.143287},{"lat":38.633693,"lng":-90.143287},{"lat":38.63322,"lng":-90.144256},{"lat":38.632362,"lng":-90.14411799999999}]
```

How can I use jQuery to convert this into a line string?  Or does leaflet have such a function?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

See the [Leaflet polyline](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline) documentation:

```
// create a red polyline from an array of LatLng points
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

where `latlngs` is your JSON result. Here's a quick [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/slead/xgL6qq73/).